# java.util.properties containsKey(key) = false & getProperty(key) has a valid value

Tags: java, spring

Got a question, under what circumstance can a `java.util.properties` object have the following?:

```
final String key =  "aRandomKey";
final boolean containsKey = propertiesObject.containsKey(key); //returns false
final String keyValue= propertiesObject.getProperty(key); // returns a valid value , in this instance a String.
```

I have encountered the above where I am setting database Properties (via `setDataSourceProperties` API) on a Hikari Datasource within a Spring `@Configuration` file and then have a custom database driver that pulls the properties to conduct further processing based on the properties and due to the containsKey inconsistency I had to rewrite a method and kind of baffled.

Comment: What is `java.util.properties`? I do not know of this package. I even double-checked the Javadocs and it wasn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)).

The `getProperty` does not have to behave like `HashTabel.get` and can and will try to get property from nested default tables.

It also does not override `containsKey` method and wont be doing nested search when this method is called.

Comment: Or to say it in much simpler words: `getProperty` also checks the default properties (see [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#defaults)), whereas `containsKey` ignores the defaults and just checks the actually set properties. Example: http://ideone.com/qqQ501

Comment: Thanks guys, this explains it. Is this a normal behavior? Do you think this should be considered normal logical behavior? Meaning in this case, you can get a valid value via getProperty and get false from containsKey for the same exact key?

Comment: I agree that it is an unexpected behavior. But `Properties` class does not break `Map` interface contract since it does not override any of the `HashMap`'s methods. Ideally it should not extend HashMap. This class has been around since JDK1.0 and back then lots of things were not perfect in the JDK, especially with its collection framework.